# How to get passed JSON Data on Ajax Error?

Tags: django, ajax

I am using Django and Ajax.
Im my view I have:

```
class MainView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        if not request.is_ajax():
            return render(request, "main.html")
        
        # hard coded both options for testing
        return JsonResponse({"data": "xyz"}, status=400) 
        # return JsonResponse({"data": "xyz"}, status=200)
```

my ajax function looks like:

```
$("#start_calculation_button").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/",
        type: 'get',
        data: {
            ...
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        }
    })
})
```

But only the success function works? While the error part just gives back `undefined`

Any idea's why it is that way?
How can I fix it?

Comment: u need to share what you are doing in the view, share the view code? what are the scenarios of success and fail?

Comment: the view code isnt important. I hard coded it

Comment: But if you want to know its:
class MainView(View):
    def get(self, request):
         return ... (above)

Comment: yeah so it will never fail as u r not doing anything, as ajax is getting the view by the URL mentioned, so it's a success. so if u want error just change the order of the success and error response return

Comment: no, that isnt the problem i change it up for testing

Comment: i am sure that the repsones are sent correctly. both the success and error response. Its just that i cant access the response json in the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters of `success` and `error` are different, in case of a `success`, these parameters are `result`, `status`, and `xhr` whereas for `error`, the parameters are `xhr`, `status`, and `error`. You thus should parse the `xhr` data with:

```
$("#start_calculation_button").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        // ⋮
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(err.data);
        }
    })
})
```